# edac-utils on Debian 8 - Jessie

Tags: hardware, raspbian-jessie

I have Jessie installed on my Raspberry Pi Zero W system. edac-utils were installed successfully using `apt-get install edac-utils`, but I cannot use them somehow, do I need to manually set edac drivers to use this module? Is anyone using edac-utils on raspberry pi successfully?

```
$sudo edac-ctl --status
edac-ctl: drivers not loaded

$edac-util
edac-util: Fatal: Unable to get EDAC data: Unable to find EDAC data in sysfs

$sudo edac-ctl --mainboard
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/sbin/edac-ctl line 66.
```

Answer (score 0):

The Raspberry Pi does not have and does not support ECC RAM, x86 processors, SMBIOS, ACPI or anything similar.

Those tools will never work on a Raspberry Pi. There are a lot of packages which have been compiled for Raspbian in the same way - any software concerning PCI or FireWire hardware is also of no use on a Raspberry Pi, even if it is readily available via `apt-get`.

Comment: So how do I detect hardware bit flip errors or ECC error? Is there any other substitute of this?